# CSS IE 8 Issue: My submit button on search form is behind my div background color

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, submit-button

I have a test page located at http://www.candyundies.com/template_non_product.php.

In Opera, FireFox, Safari and Chrome no problems, however in IE 8
my submit button (GO) located beside my search text box, which is in its own div (search2) is under the background div color. I have tried z-index but cannot get it to display on top of the background color. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What a strange website candyundies.com sounds disgusting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `z-index` for this element through `id` or, better yet, set the backgrounds `z-index` to be beneath other elements and above the `body` if it's not the `body` itself, as you described.

Answer (score 1):

Adding position: absolute/relative and z-index 1 for example will make it visible again. (to the submit button ofcourse)

Comment: It is currently set like this: #search2{
 position: absolute;
 top: 67px;
 left:643px;
 background-color:#<?php echo $tab_color;?>;
 width:49px;
 height:47px;
}
I tried adding the z-index in there and it did not work

Comment: Add those properties to submit button

Comment: Btw you shouldn't use inline styles and well it seems that you're very novice to the topic, you should read a lot on the html and css, it's easy to learn,

Comment: Remember that if u find answer to ur question mark the answer as answered